# Why my Layout Position changes when i use appendChild() method?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am changing the text content in `<p>` tags. While setting the new text content to `<p>` tags, the sequence of `<p>` tags is changing.
Is there any way to fix the issue ?

```js
var userInput = "optin-monster";
var all_script = "Benedict_Cumberbatch ";
var all=$("p:contains(" + userInput + ")").attr('id', 'xyz');
var len_all=$('p').length;
var all_array=[];
for (var i=0; i < len_all; i++) {
  all_array.push($(all[i]).text());
}
all_array = all_array.filter(item => item);
changed_array=[];
for (var i = 0; i < all_array.length; i++) 
{ 
var indexEqu=all_array[i].indexOf("=");
var slicedVal=all_array[i].slice(indexEqu+2,indexEqu+22);
var result = all_array[i].replace(all_array[i],all_script);
var out=result+slicedVal+" Enrique_Iglesias";
changed_array.push(out);
}    
for (j= 0, n = changed_array.length; j< n; j++) {
    var line = document.getElementById("xyz");
    line.innerHTML = changed_array[j];
    document.body.appendChild(line);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>vmware</p>
<p>[optin-monster slug="wxjxpdi2nhbn7xlmmljo"]</p>
<p>product design</p>
<p>[optin-monster slug="i2nlmmljodhbn7wxjxpx"]</p>
<p>[optin-monster slug="mljodhbn7wxji2nlmxpx"]</p>
```

Purpose : The changed paragraph tags should be in there actual positions after getting new text content.

Expected :
vmware

Benedict_Cumberbatch wxjxpdi2nhbn7xlmmljo Enrique_Iglesias

product design

Benedict_Cumberbatch i2nlmmljodhbn7wxjxpx Enrique_Iglesias

Benedict_Cumberbatch mljodhbn7wxji2nlmxpx Enrique_Iglesias

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y question, as I'm certain that whatever your goal is can be done more simply. Could you please edit the question to describe the purpose of the code.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I added an answer for you below.

Comment: don't do `document.body.appendChild(line);`

Answer (score 1):

From the description of the expected output in the question, your goal is to update the content of the elements in place. As such you don't need to use `appendChild()`. You can edit the element's content in-place.

In addition, as you've included jQuery in the page already you may as well use it to simplify the logic. You can provide a function to `text()` which accepts the existing text as an argument, retrieves the `slug` value from it and returns that with the added prefix/suffix.

To get the `slug` value you can use a regular expression which you simply concatenate the other string values to:

```js
let userInput = "optin-monster";
let prefix = "Benedict_Cumberbatch"; 
let suffix = "Enrique_Iglesias"

$(`p:contains(${userInput})`).text((i, t) => {
  let slug = t.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|^[^"]*$)/)[0].replace(/"/g, '');
  return `${prefix} ${slug} ${suffix}`;
});

// non-es6 version 
/*
  $('p:contains(' + userInput + ')').text(function(i, t) {
    let slug = t.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|^[^"]*$)/)[0].replace(/"/g, '');
    return prefix + ' ' + slug + ' ' + suffix;
  });
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>vmware</p>
<p>[optin-monster slug="wxjxpdi2nhbn7xlmmljo"]</p>
<p>product design</p>
<p>[optin-monster slug="i2nlmmljodhbn7wxjxpx"]</p>
<p>[optin-monster slug="mljodhbn7wxji2nlmxpx"]</p>
```

Also note that I removed the part of the logic where you set the same `id` on all the elements. This is invalid as `id` must be unique. If you need a method of identifying these elements as a group, use a `class`.

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan,
Thats what i want .

Comment: How can we achive this without using arrow function(=>) and back ticks/grave accent( ` ) ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide a non-es6 version using standard string types and functions